# How to handle win32 services in windows 2000 platform

Tags: c, winapi, service

I ve designed a win32 service in windows XP its working fine. but the problem i'm facing is that it's not working properly in windows 2000 platform. that is stopping the service restarting the service. is there any setting or need to change in code to be done.

Comment: Could you give us more details regarding the behaviour on Windows 2000?  What exactly happens (or doesn't happen)?  Do you have any error messages or log records>

Comment: ya when i starts the service it starts and works fine..
when stop and restart the service it hangs then we need to end the task from the task manager. but this problem ll not come in windows XP. with same code....

Comment: Can you break into the service with a debugger when it has hung?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have used an API that was new on WinXP?

For an interactive applications you would get a popup about an unresolved import, if I recall correctly for services these are recorded in the system event log.

If it is hanging, take process dumps and feed them into a debugger with symbols (both Microsoft's and yours) configured. That will show you the stacks of the threads, and allow you to check for deadlocks.

Comment: @Shreekanth: Your comment to your question substantially changes the question, you should update it.